# Spliting tables into 9's

Tags: lua, lua-table

I would like to know how can I split my table into subtables of 9's.

#### Example:

```
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 }
```

#### Code shall return:

```
{ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18}, { 19, 20} }
```

How do you think is this done?

Comment: Hi, have you made any attempts at this yourself? People will be able to give direct feedback on a solution you provide, but may be more hesitant to give you an answer outright.

Comment: Could you post the code that you tried? Perhaps it will be an easy fix or suggestion to get you on track.

Comment: Sorry. I am new here, should I post it in an answer?

Comment: You can just post the code in your question, perhaps underneath the part where you put what you expected. Answers should be left for others to post.

Comment: I've added my code.

Comment: `b={}; for j=1,(#a+8)/9 do b[j]={(table.unpack or unpack)(a,9*j-8,9*j)} end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems over complicated. The task is to create a subtable every 9 elements. The code below does that:

```
a={ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 }
b={}
j=0
k=9

for i=1,#a do
    if k==9 then j=j+1; b[j]={}; k=0 end
    k=k+1
    b[j][k]=a[i]
end
```

Here, `j` tracks the number of subtables created and `k` tracks the number of elements added to a subtable. When `k` becomes 9, a new subtable is created. `k` starts at 9 to signal that.